# i3 layout loading script with no effect

Tags: i3

I saved the layout for my workspace following the docs:

```
i3-save-tree --workspace 1 > ~/.i3/layouts/ws1.json
```

Because my workspace name is a quoted string variable, I had to make a script (`~/.i3/scripts/load_layout.sh`) in order to call `i3-msg` properly:

```
i3-msg "workspace $1"
i3-msg "append_layout /home/villasv/.i3/layouts/ws$2.json"
```

Then my `~/.i3/config` file had the following for workspace setup:

```
set $ws1 "1 "
bindsym $mod+1 workspace $ws1
bindsym $mod+Shift+1 move container to workspace $ws1
exec --no-startup-id 'sh ~/.i3/scripts/load_layout.sh $ws1 1'
exec firefox
```

But the layout change does not happen after sign out and sign in. I've tried even using `exec_always` and restarting `i3`, but still no effect.

Running `sh ~/.i3/scripts/load_layout.sh "dummy" 1` successfuly creates a workspace with the layout.

Also, using `exec --no-startup-id "i3-msg 'workspace 1; append_layout ~/.i3/layouts/ws1.json'"` wil also work, almost as desired. I guess the problem happens in the script or the script call, but I don't know what.

What am I missing to make this work with workspace variable names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a two reasons this does not work:

1. You quoted the whole command in with single quotes (`'`). Single quotes are not special in *i3* configurations. That means they are not "parsed away" and thus `'sh ~/.i3/scripts/load_layout.sh $ws1 1'` as a whole is taken as the name of the command, spaces and all, instead of the command `sh` with multiple arguments.
2. Your workspace name contains a space. So, even if 1. were not an issue, it would fail because the first argument - `$ws1` - to your script is not quoted on its own. This would leads to the script getting three - `1` `` and `1` - instead of two arguments - `1 ` and `1`.

Try this exec command instead:

```
exec --no-startup-id sh ~/.i3/scripts/load_layout.sh '$ws1' 1
```

As noted the single quotes around `$ws1` will not be stripped away by the *i3* configuration parser, so they will be present when passing on the argument. Also, as *i3* is doing the replacment of `$ws1` the usual rule that shell variables are not expanded inside single quotes does not apply.

Comment: you are right that my workspace name contains a space, but it *was* also quoted, so the replacement of `$ws1` is also quoted. woudn't that solve issue 2?

Comment: No, unfortunately it would not help because the double quotes are stripped away by *i3's* configuration parser. That is one of the reasons why quoting shell commands correctly in *i3's* configuration is notoriously difficult. Especially when needing multiple levels of quotes and/or variables.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I could not find out what the problem was, but I found a simple workaround that I've discovered by trial and error.

Simply defining the workspace name without quotation marks will work fine, and won't disrupt the one-liner provided in the docs.

So my solution was the change
`set $ws1 "1 "` -> `set $ws1 1 `